# ECS: docker ps doesn't print the running task

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a cluster as well as a task on ECS.

I can see that the task is running:

[image]

And the service is active:

[image]

And the associated EC2 instance is active:

[image]

But `docker ps` on this instance prints only one container - the ECS agent. Where is my task??

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS               NAMES
8d0416bfd684        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest   "/agent"            3 hours ago         Up 3 hours (healthy)                       ecs-agent
```

Comment: Is the task continuing to run or is it getting restarted a lot? Are you sure your own the right member of the cluster?

Comment: @jordanm It's restarted a lot, like every minute

Comment: @jordanm and didn't understand your second question.

Comment: If it's restarting a lot, it's probably not running long enough for it show up in `docker ps`. Use `docker ps -a` to show containers that have exited as well

Comment: @jordanm yeah now I see it. It appears hundreds of times. Please write an answer and I will accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

By extending to @jordanm comment, I prefer to [watch](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-watch-command/) `docker ps` where container keeps restarting as ECS agent automatically remove stop container if the interval is still low then `docker ps -a` might not show because of removing old container by ECS.

```
watch docker ps
```

**ECS_ENGINE_TASK_CLEANUP_WAIT_DURATION**

> This variable specifies the time to wait before **removing any containers that belong to stopped tasks**. The image cleanup process cannot delete an image as long as there is a container that references it. After images are not referenced by any containers (either stopped or running), then the image becomes a candidate for cleanup. By default, this parameter is set to 3 hours but you can reduce this period to as low as 1 minute, if you need to for your application.

[automated_container_cleanup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/automated_image_cleanup.html)

Or to **debug** such issue with service type container, I recommend

- Increase the [unhealthy threshold](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html)
- Change CMD with working `CMD` and then debug the container if the type is Ec2